# Matching patterns not within a set of opening and closing characters e.g {}, ()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string pattern below

```
str = "nums#1#2#3{#4}#5"
```

Its there a way I can match all the `#\d+` patterns excluding the ones within the curly braces.

I am currently achieving the desired result by replace the curly braces and everything withing them with an empty string before matching.

```
str = str.replace(/\{[^}]*\}/g, '');
match = str.match(/#\d+/g);
```

Its there a way to do this in javascript regular expression without the first replacement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `{` and `}` are balanced, you can use this negative lookahead to match numbers not within `{...}`:

```js
var str = "nums#1#2#3{#4}#5";
var arr = str.match(/#\d+(?![^{]*})/g)
    
console.log(arr)
//=> ["#1", "#2", "#3", "#5"]
```

`(?![^{]*}` is a negative lookahead that asserts after a number we don't have a `}` ahead before matching a `{`

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The way is to capture all that you don't want before, example:

```
var result = txt.replace(/((?:{[^}]*}|[^#{]|#(?!\d))*)(#\d+)/g, '$1 number:$2 ');
```

Comment: Cool! but i actually want an array of matches, and the braces is still included

Comment: @JustJacob: it isn't a problem, use the same pattern and extract the capture group 2 (use the exec method in a while loop to do that.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use this one : `(?!{)#\d(?!})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ETye7s/1)

Comment: `(?!{)#` means "at this position an openning curly bracket doesn't follow and there's a # character". It's nothing more than writing only `#`.

Comment: The first group should actually be a negative lookbehind `(?<!\{)` but these ain't supported in JS so only the following part is relevant in your regex `#\d(?!})` and should be more like `#\d+(?![\d}])`

Comment: Pretty cool, and straight forward, match every `#\d` that is not preceded by a { and not followed by a }, but in `nums#1#2#3{ #9 }#5` #9 is not directly padded by {} and its return in the match. but you did answer my question straight and direct though thanks.

Comment: fair player, I appreciate ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "nums#1#2#3{#4}#5";
var result=str.match(/#\d+(?!})/g);
console.log(result);
```

you can write like this too.